# Can I avoid duplicate emails in lotus notes when I receive e-mail directly AND via a group?

Tags: lotus-notes

I've been away from Notes for a few years, and I thought I remembered Notes being smart enough to avoid sending duplicate messages when a single person is mentioned explicitly ***AND*** listed in a group.  In otherwords, I'm a member of SomeEmailGroup, and Joe User sends a message in which I'm listed in the To: field and SomeEmailGroup is listed in the Cc: field, and I get two messages.

Do I have to just live with this, or is there a way around it?  Does this suggest some misconfiguration somewhere?

(A possible clue is that one of the messages always includes MIME parts and one doesn't.  I thought this might mean the group might list internet-style addresses rather than Notes hierarchical names, but it does not.)

Comment: What version of Lotus Notes and Domino are you using?

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Sorry: we're on 8.5.3.

Answer (score 1):

This does sounds like a message split occurred at a point before the group was fully resolved properly.  I.e., it was split into a MIME version and a Notes Rich Text version because at some hop the router determined that there was at least one recipient whose settings indicate he should receive MIME and at least one recipient whose settings indicate he should receive Notes Rich Text.  I would troubleshoot by looking at the routing path for the messages, and checking the Domino Directory on each server in the path to make sure that the group has the expected members.  If it doesn't, you have a replication problem to solve in your Domino Directory.

Even if it does appear to have the appropriate members, though, the real question is whether it resolves the members properly.  There are still ways it can fail.  One reason would be that views used by the router might be corrupt.  There might be other reasons as well.  How to check? Well, lots of ways -- none of them easy, and all requiring some level of admin privileges.  Since this is superuser.com, not serverfault.com, I don't necessarily assume you're an admin.  If you are, respond back and I'll see if I can give you some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I'm a developer, but I have admin privileges where I need them.  And if I run into a wall--where I not only don't have the appropriate privileges but can't get them-- I sit two cubes away from the admin.  So I'd love to hear your troubleshooting tips.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: rhsatrhs: for some reason SU is not letting me put your username after an 'at' symbol.... so I hope you are notified of this response...

Comment: @Brandon The first thing I would do is check the RouteServers field in the two received messages.  On each of the servers that you find there, you're going to want to see how the group name is resolved.  You can do that by checking the appropriate view(s) in the Domino Directory on the relevant servers -- but off the top of my head I can't remember which views.  So the other approach is practical...

Comment: Change the Home Server in your location doc, shut down the router on that server, and try sending a message to the group. Cbeck in mail-box.  Do you already have two copies of the message, or just one? And check the Recipients field in the message(s) to see if the group has been expanded correctly.

Comment: Another way would be to make sure that the group is set up as multi-purpose, then create a database on the server with default in the ACL set to No Access, the group having Manager access, and then remove the ACL entry for your name.  Log out and log back in and try to open the database.  If it opens for you, then the server resolved the group correctly.